# Combinación de teclas para ir a la última celda con datos

Tags: excel

Tenemos una columna rellena con datos, p.e. de C2 hasta C20. Si me situo en cualquier posición de la hoja y pulso Control+Fin me posiciono en la celda C20.
Si borramos los datos desde la celda C15 hasta la C20 y desde cualquier posición de la hoja volvemos a pulsar Control+Fin se coloca de nuevo en C20. ¿Cómo se puede hacer para que vaya a C14 que és la última celda con datos?

Answer (score 3):

Tienes que eliminar las celdas, no su contenido.  Una opcion es seleccionarlas y con el menú contextual (botón derecho del ratón) elegir la opción "eliminar". Después de eso basta con cerrar el libro y volver a abrirlo.

Se pueden valorar otras opciones consultando el siguiente [enlace](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/244435/how-to-reset-the-last-cell-in-excel)

Comment: Hola, eferion. He probado lo que indicas, borrar contenido y también eliminar, ambos del menú contextual, y el resultado es el mismo, el selector se va al final de la zona donde había el útimo dato borrado. Gracias por tu rápida respuesta. Seguiremos investigando.

Comment: @PedroLucas creo que os falta cerrar el libro y volver a abrirlo...

Comment: Ok, cerrando y volviendo a abrir el libro funciona.

Comment: @PedroLucas Si esta respuesta soluciona el problema no olvides marcarlo como solución. Un saludo.

Comment: No es indispensable cerrar y volver a abrir el libro, basta con guardar.

Answer (score 2):

La otra posibilidad es usando Macros

```
Sub SetEndPos()
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange
End Sub
```

Debes posicionarte en la última celda y ejecutar la macro anterior. Funciona al menos en Excel 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo presionando **CTRL + ▼** (tecla control y tecla de dirección hacia abajo), esto lo debes hacer cuando estés posicionado en la **columna C** y estando en una fila menor a la final (14), si te encuentras en una fila mayor debes presionar **CTRL + ▲**.